# qtextstream windows x64 debug fails

Tags: qt, stdout, qfile

I'm using Qt 4.8.0 built with VS 2008 x64 in Debug.  The following line causes an exception.

```
QTextStream tf(stdout);
```

This works fine in Release x64 and Debug and Release in x86.  Specifically, the failure occurs on line 1163 of qfile.cpp

```
qint64 pos = (qint64)QT_FTELL(fh);
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Edit, here is a screen shot showing the error
[image]

Comment: does it fail only in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, it only fails in Debug mode.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce here, Linux x86_64, GCC 4.6.3. Tried debug and release. ftell() on sdtout should return -1, indicating that a pipe it's not seekable. But all this should happen gracefully. Could you post the output here, please?

Comment: I'm not sure what output you're looking for, so I provided a screen shot of the exception.  Let me know if you want more info.

Comment: Is it possible you forgot to compile one library (Log4Qt) in Debug mode ?

Comment: I have only source for Log4Qt, it gets built every time I build the project (in whatever manner I tell it to build).